# Call C# codebehind while still running JS using dataTable jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, math, datatable

So i am working with a dataTable and i am trying to be able to work the code behind of just adding which works and still use the dataTable which work just not together. the two conflict so when  i have them individually it works.

```js
$(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
  $('#btnAddToTable').on('click', function(e) {
    var counter = 1;

    var textBox1 = $("#a").val();
    var textBox2 = $("#b").val();
    var textBox3 = $("#c").val();

    table.row.add([
      textBox1,
      textBox2,
      textBox3,
    ]).draw(false);
    counter++;
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="a" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="b" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="c" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static" ReadOnly="true" />

<asp:Button Text="Add To Table" ID="btnAddToTable" OnClick="btnAddToTable_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />

<table style="max-width: 50%" class="display" id="example">
  <thead>

    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>c</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would need more details about the problem you are having but from the looks of the example this is what I can see.

You have and `OnClick` on the Asp button. This will cause a post back which any change the `$('#btnAddToTable').on('click', function(e) { ... }` function makes will be wiped away.

I am not sure exactly what you are try to accomplish but if you want to prevent the post back return false in the javascript function;

**UPDATE**

Try adding `OnClientClick="return addThirdTextBoxBeforePostback();"` to the button. Then change the jquery on click to just be a function called `addThirdTextBoxBeforePostback` and return true in the function.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="a" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="b" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static" />
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="c" AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static" ReadOnly="true" />

<asp:Button Text="Add To Table" ID="btnAddToTable" OnClientClick ="return addThirdTextBoxBeforePostback();" OnClick="btnAddToTable_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />

<table style="max-width: 50%" class="display" id="example">
  <thead>

    <tr>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>c</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
function addThirdTextBoxBeforePostback() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    var counter = 1;

    var textBox1 = $("#a").val();
    var textBox2 = $("#b").val();
    var textBox3 = $("#c").val();

    table.row.add([
      textBox1,
      textBox2,
      textBox3,
    ]).draw(false);
    counter++;
    return true;
};
```

***Disclaimer - I haven't tested this and the OnClientClick may not work right when there is OnClick. I just can't remember**

Comment: i am trying the dataTable to still work and calculate while also putting the answer from the third textbox into the dataTable at the same time

Comment: Try adding `OnClientClick="return addThirdTextBoxBeforePostback();"` to the button. Then change the jquery on click to just be a function called `addThirdTextBoxBeforePostback` and return true in the function.

Comment: do you think you can show me an example? i only have 2 months of experience so i am still learning.

Comment: When i ran it. i have no issues but the calculations arent running through im pasting in my code behind,